# How to use StreamGeometry class on Windows Phone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, draw, splines

I try to draw curve reference to [Petzold Book Block](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2009/01/canonical-splines-in-wpf-and-silverlight.html)

and I try use this in Windows Phone 8. These libraries not support `StreamGeometry` class in namespace `System.Windows.Media`.

How to try draw it on WP8? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`StreamGeometry` is not supported in Silverlight for Windows Phone. To see the full list of available classes, see [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Media%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

You will have to find another way of simulating `StreamGeometry` for your application. You should be able to simply use `PathGeometry` instead.